# Скрыть определенный label с классом

Tags: label

Делаю так $(".f_sroc > label").style.display = "none"; Не хочет работать, где ошибаюсь?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

label в классe:

```
$(".f_sroc > label").hide();
```

---

label с классом:

```
$("label.f_sroc").hide();
```

Comment: Спасибо большое))